# How to store the base64 image string in API using angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular.

My task is to convert an image in base64 string and to store that string in an API json.

I have converted the image in a string format properly but I don't know how to store that string in my backend. Please i need from you guys.

```
    HTML
    ----
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*"
    (change)="changeListener($event)">
    <div *ngIf="imageToShow">
        <img src="{{imageToShow}}" class= "center" alt="">
    </div>
    </div>

    TS
    ---
    imageToShow: string = null;

   ngOnInit() {
   this.category_info = JSON.parse
('{"category":{"image":"","name":"","description":""
,"definition":"","type":"","title":"","icon_name":""}}');
   }
    changeListener($event) : void {
      this.readThis($event.target);
    }

    readThis(inputValue: any): void {
      var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
      var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
      myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        this.imageToShow = myReader.result;
        console.log(this.imageToShow);
      }
      myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From the Base64 String, Please remove Content Type string **'data:image/png;base64,'**. You can send the Base64 content string to the Backend API as POST method using Angular HTTPClient Service.

JSON Structure:

    {
        id: 0,
        content-type: :image/png
        base64-content : "image base64 content"
    }
```